# Linux OS flashing on USB: You need to Format Disk after successful Flashing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, flash

I am seeing below a weird error message saying that I have to format the USB disk onto which I just now completed flashing the Linux OS. This is the second time. First I got same error on another USB pendrive. Should I ignore it? or what is wrong here?
the

[image]

Comment: I did format and flash. This is second pendrive. Do you think something wrong with two pendrives I have used?

Comment: Windows is accessing it after the transfer and doing what it is supposed to do. At that point you are supposed to either remove it or boot from it.

Comment: Normally Windows will ask you to format it if it has a partition with type code  / GUID that Windows recognizes / uses yet the filesystem isn't one so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore it, the USB drive is ready for use.

It's not clear what exactly you flashed there, but based on your description the root cause is that after the flash the drive is Linux-formatted. Windows can't read it, so it suggests formatting.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds assuring to me. One more thing I am struggling is to get my windows to the BIOS setup and let me make changes to boot it up from USB. As of now, I restarted the windows OS, like 5 times and I tried ESC, F2, F8, F10 buttons. I have been pressing them continuously at the startup. All I see is OS bootup safely to the login page. Also I am Admin user of the computer.

Comment: Friend, this is an entirely separate issue, you need to ask a new question. You need to provide a lot more details on your system to get an answer. Before asking a new question - try F12 immediately at the boot to open the boot menu. If this is a satisfactory answer to the original question please do accept it so this won't stay as a ghost in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Rufus* tool [here](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.22/rufus-3.22p.exe) to cross-check with one drive if the same error occurs.This is because i find BalenaEtcher tool inconsistet in flashing drives. Rufus works on Windows Os, I normally do this to check integrity of a flash disk before I install a Linux OS in it.
Make sure to install as disk image.

On boot up, you can do two things;

- Boot up the pc with f10(for HP machines) to enter BIOS setup, go to
  security / advanced,then adjust the boot options, select and move the
  flash drive up ~priority.
- Boot up with f9 key pressed, then select the disk to boot from.
  Continue with favourite installation mode.